# Time until midnight CST?

Tags: javascript, time

I have this code to calculate, based on the user's computer's time, the milliseconds until Midnight CST.
For the timezone I am in, `now.getTimezoneOffset()` returns 420, making `tmzOfst` 60.

```
function millisToMidnight() {
  var now = new Date();
  var tmzOfst = (now.getTimezoneOffset())-360; //-360 minutes = CST
  now.setHours(-(tmzOfst/60));// Adjust 'now' to CST time
  var then = new Date(now);   //make a var same as now
  then.setHours(24, 0, 0, 0); //set to midnight
  return (then - now);        //calculate difference
}
```

However, when I run this (console.log's everywhere), I get this:

```
Now = Tue Mar 07 2017 21:51:05 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time) 
tmzOfst = 120
Then = Mon Mar 06 2017 22:51:05 GMT-0700 (Mountain Standard Time)
```

Which, as you can see, correctly changes the time to CST, however, it ends up changing the date one day as well. Is there a easier way to do this? Why does it change the day?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if you want to ADJUST the hours, you need to adjust, not SET

```
now.setHours(now.getHours()-(tmzOfst/60));
```

Answer (score 0):

This should give you the milliseconds for the coming midnight.

```
function millisToMidnight() {
    var date = new Date();
    date.setDate(date.getDate() + 1);
    date.setHours(0);
    date.setMinutes(0);
    date.setSeconds(0);
    return date.getTime() - (new Date()).getTime();
}
```

Comment: you forgot milliseconds, by the way

Comment: also, your code does not take timezone into consideration like the question does